# no int input from keyboard c

Tags: c, input, menu, flush

I can't seem to get my keyboard to accept input and I'm not sure why. I have flushed the buffer (or so I think I did) and all I'm getting is BCS.

This is my menu function

```
//Menu
int menu() {
    int choice;

    do {
        printf("1)Move\n2)Display Maze\n3)Peek ahead\n");
        scanf("%i", &choice);
        while(getchar() != '\n');       
    } while(choice<=0 && choice>3);

    return choice;
}//end menu
```

This is in my main. I print the maze out first and then display the menu

```
printMaze(maze);
do
{
    choice = menu();     
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        //direction = readDirection();
        //move(maze, direction);
        printf("Hi\n");
    }// end choice

    else if(choice ==2)
        //displayMaze(maze);
        printf("Hello\n");
    else
        //peek(maze);
        printf("Goodbye\n");

} while(choice!=4);//hag doesn't kill me or i find the exit)
```

Comment: @luserdroog blinking cursor syndrome.....i have narrowed it down to right at the end of the displaying of the menu. It doesn't actually reach any of the code below that, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Use %d instead of %i.. refer http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/484622-difference-between-scanf-i-scanf-d-perhaps-bug-invs2005

Comment: @Mullaly `%i` is a little unusual, but I don't think it's *wrong*. In the page you linked, it was erroneous input (initial 0 triggers Octal mode, where 8 and 9 are illegal digits).

Comment: @Mullaly same thing. it isn't accepting anything

Comment: Voting to close as too localised. See OP's comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using.., if you are windows version of try reinstalling turbo c++ compiler and re-configuring the "TC" directories.

Comment: This is a comment/question rather than an answer. Also, did the OP mention Turbo C++ (sorry if I didn't see that)?

Comment: I actually figured it out. There was a piece of code missing from my teacher ha. but I'm using ubuntu 12.04 i386

Comment: @jogojapan: "I can't seem to get my keyboard to accept input and I'm not sure why. I have flushed the buffer (or so I think I did) and all I'm getting is BCS.

This is my menu function" where is turbo c++ in this defnition?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very up on C but....

Shouldn't you be scanning for INPUT "INSIDE" the While Loop??

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
  scanf("%i", &choice);
}while(choice<=0 && choice>3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`choice<=0 && choice>3` -> `choice<=0 || choice>3`

and

`choice!=4` // 1 <= `choice` <= 3, never `choice == 4`